# Pandas copy value from one column to other if one exist and other is NaN/Null

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import io

output = """
name    weight   performance_l    performance_r
Arash   62.2                   100       
Bash    91.2       90           79       
Kim     88.2       85           85      
Dim     92.1       90           95
Ghst    63.2       60           65      
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(output), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Above is my dataframe, I wish to work with `perfomance_l` and `performance_r`.
If one of `performance_l` and `performance_r` is Null...
copy the value that exist to other column, else, ignore all the dataframe.

Expected output:

```
output = """
name    weight   performance_l    performance_r
Arash   62.2       100          100       
Bash    91.2       90           79       
Kim     88.2       85           85      
Dim     92.1       90           95
Ghst    63.2       60           65      
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(output), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `fillna`:

```
df['performance_l'] = df['performance_l'].fillna(df['performance_r'])
df['performance_r'] = df['performance_r'].fillna(df['performance_l'])
```